# Dealing with pandas columns that have high cardinality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, encoding

I have a dataset which has a column that has `list` data. My final goal is to do a classification using this dataset. But lot of answers say is to use `One Hot Encoding`. But the problem I'm having is the column has a high cardinality value.

```
dataC_df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
```

Output

```
Age                                             82
Gender                                           3
Smoking                                          3
Chewing Betel Quid                               3
Alcohol                                          3
Clinical diagnosis                             173
Clinical presentation of the lesion            376
History of presenting complaint                 63
Medical history                                 27
Image Category (OCA/ OPMD/ Benign/ Healthy)      4
dtype: int64
```

Considering `dataC_df['Clinical diagnosis']` column,

```
arr = []
for i in dataC_df['Clinical diagnosis ']:
  arr+=i
len(set(arr))
```

Output

```
56
```

So as you can see above I have 56 unique values in all those lists that present in the `dataC_df['Clinical diagnosis']` column.

If I use one column each for every unique value I will get 56 columns. Is there a better way to deal with this kind of a situation?

Comment: It depends on many things. First do you want to classify or predict values? Second, which algorithm do you want to use (DecisionTree, Ensemble, SVM, etc), using too many categories can give surprising results. You can also reduce the cardinality by grouping some values. For you 56 clinical diagnosis maybe you can reduce the number to 4 or 5 groups only?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a SVM. I can try to reduce the clinical diagnosis into groups. But I have to check that will I be able to reduce the column to a that lower count.